# Reactjs material ui prevent re-render tabs on enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have built a material-ui based UI containing tabs in reactJS. Anytime a tab is selected, the content under that tab reloads which is causing a major performance issue because I am displaying an iFrame under one those tabs. I tried to use React.memo to ensure that the screen does not re-render because there is no change in the props but it still does.

Here is the code -

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-nxsfv?file=/video.js)

Is there a way, that once the iFrame is loaded for the first time and I switch between tabs, the iframe does not get re-rendered again?

Comment: Actually using `useMemo` does not render the component twice, HTML reloads the source of your iFrame on component mount. I've made a sandbox with `useMemo` and put a `console.count` there, you can check it's rendered only once https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-5tigs?file=/demo.js

Comment: Thanks Sabbin, but I needed the state of the compoent to be maintained after you switch the tab. If we useMemo and start the video in one tab and switch to the other tab and then switch back, the video gets loaded again from beginning. I wanted to avoid that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You check if the `value` of the current tab equals the `index` of the current tab, and only if they are equal you display the content.
Instead - just keep the content and have the Typography component control the visibility of it's content (which you already have, using the `hidden` inside the `Typography` component.

```
<Typography
  component="div"
  role="tabpanel"
  hidden={value !== index}
  id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
  aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
  {...other}
>
  {<Box p={3}>{children}</Box>}
</Typography>
```

> Note that the content will be rendered, so if you have a lot of content inside/requests to the backend/etc - all of those will be part of your DOM, even if you don't see them.

Comment: Thank you Dekel. This is helpful. When does the DOM gets flushed again in this solution?

Comment: In the above solution the DOM should not be flushed at all. If you want to force flush you should do it manually (change props/something in the component).

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript solution:

1. Wrap the tab display component in a `memo()` function call
2. Wrap the display component with the control logic (`<div style={...}`)
3. Tab change won't re-render the DOM anymore; size of tab content naturally flows by tab display component size. Flushing/update can be triggered by state changes in tab display component.

Example code:

```
  const SomeTabDisplayComponent = memo(() => {
      return <div>Whatever the tab displays</div>
  })


  const getVisibilityStyle = (hiddenCondition: boolean): any => {
      if (hiddenCondition) {
          return {
              visibility: 'hidden',
              height: 0,
          };
      }
      return {
          visibility: 'visible',
          height: 'inherit',
      };
  };

  <div style={getVisibilityStyle(value !== index)}>
      <SomeTabDisplayComponent />
  </div>
```

This solution has many advantages over the prev. answer. It doesn't use another component; doesn't mis-use "Typography" (`<p>` tag is not meant to include block content! Doing this is bad for SEO and accessibility etc.; violates web standards.); It doesn't depend on Typography's it's internal "hidden" implementation (if that one changes in the future, the upper solution will break) and it gives full control over when the re-render/DOM flush happens.